# Is it always possible to recover the univariate PMFs from the joint PMF?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given a joint probability distribution for random variables $X$ and $Y$, is it always true that the univariate PMFs of $X$ and $Y$ can be recovered using the marginalization rule, $P(X = x) = \sum_{y} P(X = x, Y = y)$?

It is indeed quite intuitive that we can find how often $X = x$ occurs if we consider how often $X = x$ occurs with each *individual* value of $Y$, and sum up all such values to get the total value of the "often-ness" of $X$. But the discrete r.v.s. $X$ and $Y$ don't need to be independent. Is it really impossible to define a joint PMF where e.g. $P(X = x) \neq \sum_{y} P(X = x, Y = y) = 0$?

In this regard, is it possible to prove that the marginalization rule, i.e. the definition of the marginal PMF, necessarily follows from the definition of the joint PMF? I've tried to prove this in various ways but failed. Indeed, I deleted a previous question because of a silly mistake I made in an attempt to prove that the marginalization rule is a consequence of the law of total probability by showing that the events $Y = y_i$ form a partition of the joint sample space.

Comment: if $\mu_{(X,Y)}$ is distribution of random vector $(X,Y)$ and $\mu_X$ is the distribution of random variable $X$, then you have $\mu_X(A) = \mu_{(X,Y)}(A \times \mathbb R)$. In the case of discrete random variables it is exactly (taking $A = \{x\}$) $\mathbb P(X=x)=\mu_X(\{x\}) = \mu_{(X,Y)}(\{x\} \times \mathbb R) = \mathbb P(X=x,Y \in \mathbb R) = \sum_{y} \mathbb P(X=x, Y=y)$